# Could not find Gson Excepiton Android

Tags: android, gson

I am stuck since two day this issue, though it was already perfect, what's going wrong kindly help me out with.

**Exception**:

```
Could not find class 'com.google.gson.Gson$1', referenced from method com.google.gson.Gson.<init>
```

Here is my gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile files('libs/notification-hubs-0.4.jar')
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.anthonycr.grant:permissions:1.0'
    compile 'com.github.johnkil.print:print:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'  
}
```

**NOTE:** Kindly do not suggest me to add gson jar in libs folder and compile I already did that, and getting another exception `java.util.zipException duplicate entry`

Any help would be appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: if you are adding the jar file please remove the line  "compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4' " from the dependencies

Comment: instead of adding jar you can use gradle entry.

Comment: adding jar and removing from dependcy giving me exception java.util.zipExeption dupliate entery

Comment: Don't add jar! Just add this line in your gradle file.

dependencies {
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.+'
}

Comment: @UmeshChauhan i did that

Comment: did you set `multiDexEnabled true` ?

Comment: yes added true @IntelliJAmiya